# Reimport SQL Server backup from an .ipynb file

Tags: python, sql-server, import, ssms, backup

At the recommendation of my boss (who doesn't remember saying it), I backed up data from several tables into an .ipynb file using the Tasks->Export Data... command in SSMS. I have finished the task that had me to set aside the data I was working with and I now need to return to my original task.

When I use Task->Import Data..., none of the delimiters are accepted by the SQL Server Import and Export Wizard. A Google search for how to import brings up plenty of Python and Jupyter articles and links, but none seem to apply. Help.FastHosts.UK has a fine tutorial, but fails to mention the delimiter selection that would allow an .ipynb file to be imported.

Can anyone tell me how to reimport data from an .ipynb stream back into SQL Server?.
[SQL Server Import and Export Wizard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0NnAe.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No answer, but everything was re-entered as inserts by parsing the file.